# Is there a way to sequentially read an Android sharedprefs file without knowing the keys?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there any way to read an Android `shared pereferences` file sequentially and without knowing the contained keys beforehand?

I have some user data stored in a shared prefs that may contain anything from 0 to about 20 values. Rather than step through each possible key to retrieve the value, it would be more efficient to just read the values that exist in the file sequentially and then process based on both teh key and value retrieved.

Comment: Yes there is. Please post ten lines of such a file.

Comment: But 20 keys is nothing so i would not care for efficiency.